# Function to get the actual dimnames()

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, names

I'd like to get the names of each dimension for a given vector, matrix, or array. Something like:

```
a = matrix(1, nrow=2, ncol=2, dimnames=list(c('a','b'),c('x','y')))

dimnames(a)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "x" "y"
```

So far, so good. If a dimension doesn't have any names, it should return NULL:

```
b = c(1:5)

dimnames(b)
# NULL
```

Also works fine. However, when I do:

```
a2 = matrix(1, nrow=2, ncol=2)

dimnames(a2)
# NULL
```

This gives `NULL`, even though there are two axes names which are **each** `NULL`. Hence I would expect the result to be:

```
# [[1]]
# NULL
# [[2]]
# NULL
```

**instead of** the one given by `dimnames()`.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built into base R. But it's fairly easy to write your own:

```
dimnames2 <- function(x) {
  if (is.vector(x)) {
    list(names(x))
  } else {
    d <- dimnames(x)
    if (is.null(d)) {
      rep(list(NULL), length(dim(x)))
    } else {
      d
    }
  }
}

dimnames2(1:10)
dimnames2(matrix(1:10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a one-liner to do essentially what Hadley is doing (independently derived, *I swear* ;-)):

```
> dimnames2 = function (x) dimnames(x) %else% rep(list(NULL), length(dim(x)))
> dimnames2(a)
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "x" "y"
> dimnames2(a2)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

Oh yeah, I cheated. `%else%` is equivalent to the null-coalesce operator in C#, or `or` in Perl, Ruby, PHP …:

```
`%else%` = function (a, b) if (identical(a, FALSE) || is.null(a) || length(a) == 0) b else a
```

Comment: I like the `%else%`, you might want to add a `FALSE` clause: `x=F %else% print("this is working")`

Comment: Not exactly the same because your function works only for `matrix` but the op want a result for `vector` too. BTW, this %else% function is really handy

Comment: And for `table`, and other weird data types. So I call an `as.array()` in the beginning, that should be fine.

Comment: @user538603 Good catch. Copy&paste error, *and* I noticed a bug in the actual function I’m using.

Comment: Except the dim of a vector is NULL, and length NULL is 0 so you get inconsistent output for `dimnames2(1:10)`